# Hard to read an armadillo field data structure

Tags: c++, armadillo

When I try to write a field object in armadillo in C++ and then read it, it works well. The sample code is:

```
//write the data to signal.bin file 
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("signal.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);
//CLASS_NUM is the size of field, signal is the data need to save;
outfile.write((char*)&CLASS_NUM, sizeof(int)); // sizeof can take a type
outfile.write((char*)&signal, sizeof(field<mat>));
outfile.close();

//read the saved data
ifstream inFile( "signal.bin", ios::binary );
int K;
inFile.read( reinterpret_cast< char* >( &K ), sizeof( int ) );
field<mat> Input_Signal(K, 1);
inFile.read( reinterpret_cast< char* >( &Input_Signal ), sizeof( field<mat> ) );
inFile.close();
```

I check it by output the data, they matched. However, when I comment out the write part in the code, which means I have a signal.bin file and I need to read it(the second part of the code),

```
//read the saved data
 ifstream inFile( "signal.bin", ios::binary );
 int K;
 inFile.read( reinterpret_cast< char* >( &K ), sizeof( int ) );
 cout << K << endl;
 field<mat> Input_Signal(K, 1);
 inFile.read( reinterpret_cast< char* >( &Input_Signal ), sizeof( field<mat> ) );
 inFile.close();
 cout << Input_signal;
```

then I have an output like:

```
1
[field column 0]
Segmentation fault: 11
```

1 is the dimension of the field, so I know it can be read from the file, then why I can not read the matrix saved in the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [field class](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#field) already has functions for [saving and loading](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#save_load_field) fields which contain instances of `mat`.

For example:

```
field<mat> F(2,3);

F(0,0).randu(4,5);
F(1,0).randu(6,7);

F.print("F:");
F.save("signal.bin");

field<mat> G;

G.load("signal.bin");
G.print("G:");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is most likely that you write the structure `field<mat>` without thinking about the actual data in the class.

For example, pointers to memory is only valid within a single process. If you write a pointer to a file and attempt to read and use it from another program, that pointer no longer points to allocated data, and dereferencing this pointer will lead to *undefined behavior* and most likely a crash like the one you have.

You need to study the subject of [*serialization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Joachim, I will read the subject you recommend.